# How to wait for a loader inside a button to complete loading?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I need to wait for a specific loader to complete loading once the button has been pressed, please take a look at the following image below:
[image]

As you can see from the image above, once the button has been pressed the ajax loader appears inside the button.

I have created the following selector to locate the button:

```
//form[contains(@id, 'messageform')]//button/span
```

Currently accepting the request (Clicking on the button) fails my test case as the script continues to the next test steps without waiting for the loader to complete.

I have tried the following and more, with no luck:

- Injecting JS to wait for the page to fully load.

  ```
  ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = driver -> ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
  ```
- ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element)

  ```
  WebDriver driver = getDriver();

  WebDriverWait exists = new WebDriverWait(driver, timer);
  exists.until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(
          ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element)));
  ```

Any ideas?

Comment: Code trials for `Injecting JS to wait for the page to fully load` and `ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(element)`?

Comment: @DebanjanB examples attached.

Comment: As you requested in a comment below, I can post a solution but first I will need some more information. Please post the HTML of the `BUTTON` before the click, after the click and while the spinner is inside, and after the spinner is gone and the `BUTTON` is in its final state. Also, please post HTML (for these three states) as text and not as an image. It's MUCH easier for us to use the HTML in a sample page, create locators, etc. by using the text which isn't available as an image. Once you do that, message me and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `.stalenessOf()` to wait until an element is no longer attached to the DOM.

Something like this (tweak to your case):

```
WebElement somePageElement = driver.findElement(By.id("someId"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
// do something that changes state of somePageElement
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(somePageElement));
```

And the good thing is you don't have to handle any exceptions.

Alternatively, you can also create a method and handle exceptions like so:

```
public static void WaitForCommission (WebDriver driver) throws Exception {
    for (int second = 0; second++) {
        if (second >= 30) fail("timeout");
        try { 
            if (IsElementActive(By.id("someElementID"), driver)) 
                break; 
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

private static boolean IsElementActive(By id, WebDriver driver) {
    WebElement we =  driver.findElement(id);        
    if(we.isEnabled())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Your use of `IsElementActive()` is confusing and unnecessary. What does "Active" mean in Selenium terms? You are checking for `.isEnabled()` so why not call it `IsElementEnabled()`? But at that point why do you need that method at all when all you are doing is `driver.findElement().isEnabled()`? That method already exists in Selenium so no need for a wrapper that just adds unnecessary complexity. Also, Enabled means nothing unless you are checking an `INPUT`. All elements that are visible return `true` when checked for enabled so why not check for isVisible?

Comment: Also, you are writing code that does a wait for "Active" in `WaitForCommission()`. Selenium already provides `WebDriverWait()` for this... don't write what's already been written. The whole of `WaitForCommission()` should be `new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));`.

Comment: @JeffC would you be able to post the complete code for your solution?

Comment: Exactly. @JeffC, it would be nice to use these efforts to share your suggestions(restructured code) with us, we all can learn from it. And you would have helped someone.

Comment: @pasignature I left OP a message on the question. Once I have the answers to those questions, I will leave an answer.